Error: unable to confirm transaction. This can happen in situations such as transaction expiration and insufficient fee-payer funds
1. Description of my context on api.mainnet-beta.solana.com

Token machine made with Windows 11 remote PC
Connected to Sol network by api.mainnet-beta.solana.com

1.1  Detailed description coming from solana config get
Config File: C:\Users\alain.config\solana\cli\config.yml
RPC URL: https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com
WebSocket URL: wss://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/ (computed)
Keypair Path: C:\Users\alain.config\solana\id.json
Commitment: confirmed
1.2  Showing little balance before doing transfer instruction -- solana balance
Result returned by Solana after the instruction :  solana balance:
0.110298253 SOL
2.    Description of my problem
Here, the best thing to do is probably to:
i) List the Solana Instruction (solana transfer).
ii) List the result that I get (error indicated in the topic of the question).
2.1 Solana instruction used (solana transfer + spl-token create-token + others)
Knowing that I did this instruction very often since a few years (solana transfer), I am wondering why I get this message while there is still money in the account.  It can not be a Solana congestion, as I check on status.solana.com and I also did other transactions that went thru immediately, as always (Sol is the best!).
solana transfer --allow-unfunded-recipient CKDvoZNy?????sJhdfAt8vfZs 0.1
2.2  The results that I get after I type the instruction "solana transfer"
Error: unable to confirm transaction. This can happen in situations such as transaction expiration and insufficient fee-payer funds
3.0  My analysis, my conclusions and the results I got up to now (not working?)
3.1  My analysis
i) The error code states that:
Error: unable to confirm transaction. This can happen in situations such as:
a) transaction expiration
b) insufficient fee-payer funds
ii) There is enough money to fund this transaction.  However, all transactions that require money do not work due to insufficient funds...  So, I do not know, since there is money when I do "solana balance"?  Is it possible that I have a "hidden nonce transaction" on my account?  I do not know if it is possible to have a hidden nonce placed by a third party authority?
iii) I did not consider the possibility of hidden nonce.  So, the problem must come from id.json or config.yml or any other file(s) with problems or my link to the RPC (cluster mainnet-beta), as if all was working well in my configuration, since there is enough money, the tranction would be confirmed immediately.
iv) Solana cannot confirm the transaction due to an error on my side in my configuration files or my link to Solana cluster mainnet-beta.  It is also possible that there is a problem only for token machines but I doubt, as everything else works fine and status.solana.com says all is ok, at the time of writing this text and doing test.
3.2  My proposed solution to my own problem
i- uninstall solana remote pc set up.
ii- reinstall solana remote pc set up.
iii- Do the transaction again on a new remote PC set up with solana mainnet-beta cluster.
3.3  My results
I still have the same problem after I reinstall all...
4.   My question to this board
What is going on?  Do you think it is my remote PC set up that is deficient or???
i) Naturally, I tried with less money in the transfer, so to be sure it is not the problem (0.07 Sol, 0.03 Sol, 0.01 Sol but not less).
ii) Naturally, I searched in knowledge databases but I did not find what I was looking for, otherwise, I would not be in this board asking this question.  I know the solution as to be very simple.
If I find the answer before someone proposed an answer for me, I will post it here.

Does this answer your question? Getting Transaction Expiration Error on Mainnet

Thank you for your post and updates!
I am facing the same issue on the mainnet-beta. I tried your proposed solution, but unfortunately, I am getting the same error message:
"Error: unable to confirm transaction. This can happen in situations such as transaction expiration and insufficient fee-payer funds"
Do you have any other ideas?
Used version:
solana-cli 1.18.4 (src:356c6a38; feat:3352961542, client:SolanaLabs)
Thank you in advance!

Dear GBM, look my own answer to my own question below.
solana transfer CKDvoZNyNP????-???dfAt8vfZs 0.1 --allow-unfunded-recipient --with-compute-unit-price 0.000006 --config C:\Users????.config\solana\cli\config.yml
I hope it will help others, as it should work this way. IN brief, I understand that some users might be using "priority fees" in order to boost their transactions. When this happens, if one does not pay more, the transaction expires, due to other all passes before.
Naturally, if you have contacts at Solana Labs, please inform them about this little problem.
Dr. AJSP.

Yes, I already tried that command from your own answer, but unfortunately, it didn't work for me. I am getting the same error message.

Please make sure that you write the instruction fully in accordance with Solana rules.  I recommend  using:  solana transfer --help
And, after, follow the rules.  Unless you have another problem or Sol have a problem, it shall work.

GBM, I had the same problem again today.  I think it comes from persons that are clogging the network (Sol much better than others, so they want to make us look bad!).
I fix the problem immediately with this instruction, where you would have to replace ? by what is pertinent for your context.  Please tell me if it works:
C:\Users???n????s????l>solana transfer CKDvo?????JhdfAt8vfZs 0.025 --allow-unfunded-recipient --with-compute-unit-price 0
.00001 --config C:\Users???in.config\solana???\config.yml
And, the transfer passed immediately.

It worked with the new --with-compute-unit-price 0.00001. Thank you very much for sharing this solution here. All the best for you!

Thank you GBM.  Do not forget to rate my post by clicking on the up arrow, at the left.

Clarifications added on April 7th, 2024, after the problem continues to persist:
I believe this new delay is a little war between BTC and Sol, due to the difference in overall fees.  Sol being much more advantageous that BTC now, they try to make Sol look bad with these fake delays that are indeed reals.  Without having evidence (sol status is 100%, so all should be fast: https://status.solana.com), I think some BTC users are clogging the Sol network with fake transfers that have a little 0.000001 SOL extra fees, so that all other transactions are put in the queue.
Answer to my own question above: April 5th, 2024:
I succeeded in transferring sol.  Here is the modified instruction that I used:
solana transfer CKDvoZNyNP????-???dfAt8vfZs 0.1 --allow-unfunded-recipient --with-compute-unit-price 0.000006 --config C:\Users????.config\solana\cli\config.yml
I hope it will help others, as it should work this way.  IN brief, I understand that some users might be using "priority fees" in order to boost their transactions.  When this happens, if one does not pay more, the transaction expires, due to other all passes before.
Maybe it will work with the regular instruction also.  I do not know. .
============  My original answer of April 4th, 2024 above with a solution  that should work for other cases where there is a mess in the configuration files of remote PC ======
